# how to predefine associated model foreign key in django

Tags: django

i created 2 model and both are linked to each other, i created create function view inorder to create the model object. just check my code and read more to know

**models**

```
class group(models.Model):
group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
group_user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.group_name} group'



class comments(models.Model):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = 
    models.ForeignKey(group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user} comments'
```

**views**

```
def create(request,pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.user
        author = request.user
        message = request.POST['message']
        group = group.objects.GET[pk]
        message = 
comments(user=author,message=message,name=name,group=group)
    message.save()
    return HttpResponse('')
```

**for user i can just type request. user in this case how can auto insert group id from the google adress bar**

**eg:**

group = self.request['pk']

**pls help me in this case**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the user that is logged to represent `group`, you only have to make

```py
group = request.user
```

See, a `ForeignKey` isn't actually just the `pk` of the model, it is the complete model. So to define a `ForeignKey` you have to do

```py
comments.objects.get(pk=1).group = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Try this and let me know!

Comment: exactly where do i need to add this?

Comment: instead of typing `group =  group.objects.GET[pk]`, type what I said